# How to embeded postgresql into project?

Tags: windows, postgresql

I want to embeded posgresql. i try to print help. there's no options to read config. but the weird. postgres read config from -D options, the file is `postgresql.conf` that create from initdb.exe. whichis data directory. but the config can set data dir location. so for me is weird management. why not like usual application. just have command to read config file. the real problem is postgres log give error `dont know where the lib folder`. from postgresql structure folder lib 1 up from bin.

```
posgresql
postgresql\lib
postgreseql\bin
```

what i want is lib folder inside bin.

```
project
project\bin
project\bin\lib
```

i try to set config that relate to library name, nothing help

```
dynamic_library_path 'c:\project\bin\lib'
local_preload_libraries
shared_preload_libraries
```

command that i use to start postgres server

```
pg_ctl start -s -W -D data -l log/system.log
```

Comment: The problem is 1) You not reading the docs. See [File locations](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-file-locations.html), [Setting parameters](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-file-locations.html) 2) Postgres is really not designed to be an embedded database. 3) You have not presented a clear definition of what you want to achieve.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver i already read that before create this question. if u read the file location documentation. it explains command that set location like datadir, config, hbb. but by default when initdb. that config inside data. and progress read config inside that init data. if i change the binary location. the binary ask for lib. bin and lib in same level. the binary can't find lib. i look for that command to set progress to wheres to load lib.

Comment: 1) You are using Postgres not progress. 2) You did not read the file location documentation because at the bottom of the page it tells you exactly what to do for your situation.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver i know config_file,  `pg_ctl -o "-c config_file=c:/config.conf"` but i cant set wheres postgres to load lib folder. or to set the parent directory. by default, postgress load share folder and lib folder same level as bin. i cant set it.

Comment: AFAIAK that can only be done on compiling using `--libdir=DIRECTORY` per [Configure options](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/install-procedure.html#CONFIGURE-OPTIONS).

Comment: @AdrianKlaver exactly thats what i think. but i still hope theres command that can set that thing. i will compile from source. cause, i will ship it to end-user. it awk to have that kind name share and lib at root project. ty man.

Comment: As I said before Postgres is not designed to be an embedded database and per discussions on the [pgsql-general](https://www.postgresql.org/list/pgsql-general/) mailing that is not going to change. There are other programs better suited for this e.g. SQLite.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver i see theres advantage with postgresql split file into many segment, than only in single file.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure in which programming language or IDE you want to use PostgresSQL. Usually it is easiest to simply include the proper Nuget packages. And it is getting even more easier if you chose to use the EntityFramework to access your data.

Comment: im using nodejs. i want to run server from process. from documentation. it should run from `pg_ctl`  cause to run from postgres directly. it need make some other work. like create user and give some permission. that `pg_ctl` do. with `pg_ctl` it can pass argument to posgress with `-o`. is theres no option from posgress to read config?